# Simplifying the polynomial for integration

Tags: calculus, polynomials

[image]

Hi,

I am trying to find the length of the function above from $x = 1$ to $x = 2$. I applied the length formula but I was not able to simplify it past $\sqrt{x^6 + \frac 12 + \frac 1{16x^6}}$. Can someone please walk me through the simplification steps so I can integrate it?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I should have clarified my question further. How would I go about simplifying the polynomial in the equation given by OC-Sansoo?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $x^6 + \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{16x^6} = \left(x^3+\dfrac{1}{4x^3}\right)^2$

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was told that before but don't know the approach to take. Is this a difference of squares problem?

Comment: @user3474748: Integrate $x^3+\frac{1}{4x^3}$ from $1$ to $2$. Since the expression is positive from $1$ to $2$, the square root of its square is itself.